# Convert JSONto GeoJSON or Geometry Format in PostgreSQL\PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, json

Assuming that if I run a query in my database like this

```
select coordinate_json from location
```

It will return coordinate_json column with value like this (example for one row):

```
"{\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [96.25518281124721, 4.335420234501272]}"
```

The problem is, every time I run this query to convert coordinate_json to geometry column :

```
select ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(coordinate_json) from location
```

I will get this error message:

```
ERROR:  function st_geomfromgeojson(json) does not exist
```

Maybe coordinate_json format, as I wrote above, is not match with GeoJSON format remind that there're backslash, so how can I convert that to Geometry Column?

Comment: Where did you get coordinate_json from. Usually, when you see slashes in front of the quotes it is for escaping for the purposes of sending down the wire. But, you certainly, don't want it to be saved in the db like that.

Comment: This also works, select st_geomfromgeojson(replace('{\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [96.25518281124721, 4.335420234501272]}', '\',''));
, but is a bit hacky. You could run an update to get rid of all the back slashes on the column and then st_geomfromgeojson will work as expected.

Comment: Long story, i got it from some python manipulating to return variable and for some reason, that variable was saved as geojson to databases..

Comment: Ok, so, if you run the replace function to remove the \, then your problem is solved?

Comment: Thanks, this helping me so much, but the problem is, how to replace double quotes to single quotes remind that in my example there're double quotes covering that json format..

Comment: The double quotes are correct. Look at my query above.

Comment: Yes i mean the double quotes in the beginning and the end of json statement. In your query, you're manually change double quotes int the beginning and the of statement to single quotes..

Comment: replace(coordinate_json, '"{', '{'); etc

Answer (score 2):

I'm unclear of exactly your problem so I'll cover both bases..

### If you're working with literals

Use [`$$` dollar-quoted string literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html). When this returns text..

```
SELECT $${"type": "Point", "coordinates": [96.25518281124721, 4.335420234501272]}$$;
```

And this returns JSON,

```
SELECT $${"type": "Point", "coordinates": [96.25518281124721, 4.335420234501272]}$$::json;
```

Then this will work,

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($${"type": "Point", "coordinates": [96.25518281124721, 4.335420234501272]}$$);
```

### If you're working with database columns of type `json`;

If you're getting this error

```
ERROR:  function st_geomfromgeojson(json) does not exist
```

Then you're doing something like this

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(jsonCol);
```

But, that [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) doesn't accept type json (though it really should -- I'll patch it later). Instead you need to do this

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(jsonCol::text);
```

Comment: It will return this error : "ERROR:  unknown GeoJSON type", maybe because of backslash and double quote in my json value, that why i tried to remove them

Comment: @Faizalprabowo What you're saying doesn't add up: which one is the problem. Is the problem escaping, or is this already JSON in the database that you want to call `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()` -- if so just cast it `::text`

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have PostGIS installed correctly (the tip being function ST_GeomFromGeoJSON does not exist)?

This fails for me:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON("{\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [96.25518281124721, 4.335420234501272]}");
```

(with `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "type"` )

but this works:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [96.25518281124721, 4.335420234501272]}');
```

Comment: Yes i 'm, It seem that the problem is on back slash and double quotes in my json field..

Answer (score -3):

This is my solution refer to [@John Barça](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/429/john-bar%C3%A7a) suggestion

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(replace(replace(replace(coordinate_json, '\"', '"'),'"{','{'), '}"', '}')) FROM Table_name
```

Thanks [@John Barça](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/429/john-bar%C3%A7a) and [@matej](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/82672/matej)..

Comment: this is horrible. I'm not sure what you're doing here, but just don't! See my answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218109/6052